Spark Thrift throws TTransportException every time the client disconnects
I am running Thrift like this, notice I am using latest apache/spark-py docker image unmodified:
docker run -e SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE=true
 -p 10000:10000 -it apache/spark-py /opt/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh
 --master local[*]

This is my simplified Java program that connects to the Thrift server and executes a query. The program works fine.
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class ThriftClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default";
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "", "");
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT 1234");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Even though the client program works fine, and prints the query result, when the client exits, I see an exception in the server log. It looks like this:
24/07/05 21:36:17 ERROR TThreadPoolServer: Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readLength(TSaslTransport.java:374)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:451)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:433)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.read(TSaslServerTransport.java:43)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:425)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:321)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:225)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:52)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:310)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am using Spark version v3.4.0 and hive-jdbc-2.3.9-standalone.jar
I have tried an older version of Spark docker image, and it too has the same problem.
What's the reason for this exception and how can I make it go away?

The specific exception claims to happen during "read()" according to your provided stack trace unfortunately that doesn't explain about unless you know the documentation. I assume that means it is able to connect to the db, but then it is extremely odd that it cannot execute such a basic select. Have you tried connecting to you db through a normal server explorer? To see if there is a connection issue? Maybe the port forwarding from docker is not setup?

Connecting to the db works fine. The client program seems to work fine. It is able to execute the query and print the results. But each time, the server throws an exception.

Additional info: If you put the query in a loop that executes 5 times, you don't get 5 exceptions on the server. You don't get any exceptions when the query executes. When the client exits, that's when you get the exception. So it seems when the server can no longer read from the client it gets upset.
